# Append brackets at the end in the CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

At the beginning and at ending of the contents I have to append the brackets my csv file looks like this

```
        date1,success,failure,count
        1427653800,95,65,160
        1427653800,30,10,40
        1427740200,10,8,18
        1427740200,30,38,68
        1427826600,38,20,58
        1427826600,60,10,70
        1427653800,15,15,30
        1427653800,10,10,20
```

After adding brackets the contents should look like this: [1427653800,95,65,160] 
My php code  is below:

```
    <?php
        $list = array ('date1', 'success', 'failure','count');

        $sql = "SELECT (SUBSTRING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1),1,10)),success,failure,count from h_statistics;";
              $users_profile_user_id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

          $fp = fopen("data.csv", "w");

            fputcsv($fp, $list);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_profile_user_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {

          fputcsv($fp, $row);

        }

        fclose($fp);
    ?> 

this is my conn.php file ,please suggest me on this
```

Comment: plz try and let me know!!

Comment: @satish $row is an Array, it'll not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to use this query

```
 $sql = "SELECT CONCAT('[','',(SUBSTRING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1),1,10))),success,failure,CONCAT(count,'',']') from h_statistics";
```

it give you result like [1427653800,95,65,160] so no need to do any code in you while loop

Answer (score 0):

Try to append and prepend the brackets :

```
$row[0] = '['.$row[0];
$row[3] .= ']';
fputcsv($fp, $row);
```

Comment: @satish, okay will try it out

Comment: @ akram okay will try it out and see

Comment: @ akram if i put, $row[0] = '['.$row[0];
$row[3] .= ']';
fputcsv($fp, $row); inside while loop im getting output as  date1,success,failure,count
        1427653800,95,65,160,[,] ,but i need like this  [1427653800,95,65,160]

Comment: @satish if i use "[".$row."]"  inside the while loop im getting, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\highcharts1\Conn.php on line 40

Comment: @ Miglen  im getting Undefined index: date1 in C:\wamp\www\\StatisticsDisplay\highcharts1\Conn.php on line 37 and date1,success,failure,count
1427653800,95,65,160],[   im getting like this instead of [1427653800,95,65,160]

Answer (score 0):

try with my function which is adding your text to the first and last element of the associative array:

```
<?php

function array_brackets($array,$prefix,$suffix){

//add prefix to the first element
end($array);
$key = key($array);
$array[$key] = $prefix . $array[$key];

//add sufix to the last element
reset($array);
$key = key($array);
$array[$key] = $array[$key] . $suffix;

return $array;
}


$list = array ('date1', 'success', 'failure','count');

$sql = "SELECT (SUBSTRING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1),1,10)),success,failure,count from h_statistics;";
      $users_profile_user_id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

  $fp = fopen("data.csv", "w");

    fputcsv($fp, $list);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_profile_user_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

  fputcsv($fp, array_brackets($row,"[","]"));

}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: Example might be found here: http://codepad.org/CWttUAiC Drop me a line if it works for you.

Comment: @user3753411 can you please execute and give me the output:
 <?php

    $list = array ('date1', 'success', 'failure','count');

    $sql = "SELECT (SUBSTRING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1),1,10)),success,failure,count from h_statistics;";
          $users_profile_user_id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

      //$fp = fopen("data.csv", "w");

      //fputcsv($fp, $list);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_profile_user_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {

      //fputcsv($fp, array_brackets($row,"[","]"));
   print_r($row);
      exit;
    }

    //fclose($fp);
 
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

Please run this code and give me the output:

```
<?php

$list = array ('date1', 'success', 'failure','count');

$sql = "SELECT (SUBSTRING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1),1,10)),success,failure,count from h_statistics;";
      $users_profile_user_id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

  //$fp = fopen("data.csv", "w");

  //fputcsv($fp, $list);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_profile_user_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

  //fputcsv($fp, array_brackets($row,"[","]"));
  print_r($row);
  exit;
}

//fclose($fp);

?>
```